# Freeradius nas.sql table field description

Tags: mysql, nas, freeradius

Anyone knows the function of this fields on nas.sql table?

> ports int(5)
>
> server varchar(64)
>
> community varchar(50)

I think community is for checkrad snmp check, but the others i dont know how to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Server is the virtual server the client is bound to, I have absolutely no idea about ports, and yes community would likely be for checking simultaneous use via the checkrad SNMP utility.